# Should we unit test predicate methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I am working on unit testing and I am trying to increase the line coverage to 90% of a class. The class contains lot of predicate methods which only compare some of its fields and based on that it returns true or false. 
My question is, should I write unit tests for those predicate methods or not. 
Currently, I have written unit tests which just initialize the object and set its fields and then assert if return value of predicate is correct.

For example:

```
public boolean isScheduled() {
   return getShippingDate() != null;
}
```

How should I unit test it and what should be the unit test method name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you, add a test for the code even if there is a small piece of logic involved in there.

My preference for naming would be like:

> methodName+ExpectedReturnValue+Behaviour

For example, in your case, I would name it as

> isScheduledShouldReturnTrueWhenShippingDateIsNotNull - positive case
>   isScheduledShouldReturnTrueWhenShippingDateIsNotNull - negative case

Follow the same naming convention across the repository (not necessarily the one that I suggested). You can also merge both cases in one test.

Remember that tests are the documents, so it is okay to have the method name verbose.

Code:

```
@Test
public void isScheduledShouldReturnTrueWhenGetShippingDateIsNotNull() {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    classA.setShippingDate("date");

    boolean isScheduled = classA.isScheduled();

    assertTrue(isScheduled);
}
```

PS: Ideally, the motive should never be like increasing the coverage to get some good reports. What matters is the quality of the tests.